# symfony form isvalid eqauls false but has no error

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on a symfony project which is already live and use doctrine. The problem I describe below is new and I'm certain it was caused by me but I can not confirm this as I'm unsure how to debug.

I have a simple form (it submits two fields) and I can see both these values have been submitted correctly by dumping the following:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

The problem is that although I can see the submitted values, the form does not pass validation:

```
if ($form->isValid() === false)
```

This used to pass validation, perhaps 4 weeks ago so its something I've done recently.

I have dumped `$form->getErrors(true);` to see if I can find the error but it returns this:

```
RenderController.php on line 20:
FormErrorIterator {#685 ▼
 -form: Form {#691 ▶}
 -errors: []
}
```

So unless I'm mistaken, no errors are found here as the errors is empty.

I have read that `$form->isValid()` checks the data model, i.e. the underlying entity objects.

I have recently made changes to an entity. I did this by first adding a field to the database and then going into the entity class to updating it manually.

Is it possible that I have done something wrong when adding the new field? What confuses me is that are other forms which use the new field and I have not experienced any issues with.

Should I have not done this manually? How do I debug the form further?

Comment: `doctrine:schema:validate` to see if your database is in sync.
If you are using git, checkout `git bisect` to find out the defected commit.

Comment: To check if it's valid you normally use: `if ( $form->isValid() )`, which returns true if it's valid. If you want to check if it's NOT valid, then use `if ( !$form->isValid() )`. So you don't need the extra `=== false`.

Comment: `doctrine:schema:validate` says mapping files are correct.

Comment: @Alvin Bunk are you implying that using '===' false won't find an invalid form?

Comment: `===` is used to compare the same `types`. Since you are checking if it's invalid and `isValid()` returns a boolean, then you should use `if( !$form->isValid() )`. Do you want me to post this as an answer? I'm not sure if this address the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: === false might be not very pretty but it's not wrong either. In fact it makes clear that you are actually checking for the boolean value and not for other "falsy" values such as empty string or null

Comment: `foreach ($form->getErrors(true) as $error) {
     echo $error->getMessage();
}`

Get error and then post here what exactly error is.

Comment: @AnkitVadi the foreach returns nothing.

Comment: @AlvinBunk Like you said, the if statement doesn't appear to be the problem but thanks for making me aware of this.

Comment: Did you put `exit();` after foreach? Because if you are redirected to anywhere else or renders anything after foreach, this will not show you anything.

Comment: @AnkitVadi Yes, I put an exit but this did not show anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely caused by how validation works in symfony.
As you correctly wrote, $form->isValid() doesn't actually validates the form itself. Instead the underlying entity is validated.

Now here comes the tricky part: Not only fields present in the form are validated, but every field of the entity. If your form only represents part of your entity then the described effect occurs.
Probably one of the added fields has the NotBlank assertion (or similar) but isn't present in your form. For a new entity, this will always fail. And because the field is not present in the form, there is also no error in the form.

To solve the problem, either extend you form, remove the assertions from the new fields or take a look at [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html)

Comment: It may take me a little while to work through this suggestion but it is inline with other answers I've read discussing similar issues with isValid() when it returns no error. Thank you. This answer has helped and I will post back the cause asap.